# Dataframe change existing columns values to a single particular value

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

have a df with values

df

```
0      1
sun   NaN
moon  123
cat   NaN
dog   yatch
```

Turn the values that are already present to pass and NaN to fail

expected Output

```
0      1
sun   fail
moon  pass
cat   fail
dog   pass
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) with [`Series.isna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isna.html):

```
df[1] = np.where(df[1].isna(), 'fail', 'pass')
```

Comment: can i use this if only pass should be provided    `df[1] = np.where(df[1].isna(), 'pass')`

Comment: @theUnknown no, always is necessary specify else value.

Answer (score 0):

A variation without `numpy`:

```
mask = df[1].isna()
df.loc[mask, 1] = 'fail'
df.loc[~mask,1] = 'pass'
```